# Writing an AI: screen capture and input

Tags: c++, python, windows, directx, artificial-intelligence

I'm considering a pet project to write an AI for a simple game on Windows (C++/python preferred). Can you instruct me on what is the way to go for grabbing simple screen captures, so that I can do some very simple object recognition/find out what is such and such pixel color basically.

And also I'd need to manage input (moving mouse, click etc)? I'm mostly a linux guy, so I bet here I'd need to use some DirectX API to inject events?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I once did that for breaking the record for Bejeweled Blitz. Turns out computers are much faster than *all* humans who don't use cheats.

Since the game I created a robot for was a flash game running inside a browser a few years ago, I only needed to use ordinary Win32 API calls to grab the screen content and to send mouse events.

You can start reading here a little bit about [grabbing screen content](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vssmartdevicesnative/thread/70cd890f-0c82-40a5-97a8-93b9daa50b70/), and here about [simulating mouse input](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171548.aspx).

I think you'd be better off using .NET instead of C++. If you're really fond of Python, try IronPython, since it's .NET based, it'll make interfacing with the Windows APIs a lot easier.

Comment: Your second link points to the same URL as the first. But I assume in the end it'll point him to [SendInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) anyhow.